# Can I make jelly from canned jalapeños?

Tags: jelly

I've got 10 cans of jalapeños opened and emptied into Tupperware  because the cans are the right size for a project, but I don't need the peppers.  I'm trying to use the peppers, and I thought jelly might be a way to do that.

Can I use jalapeños from a can when the recipe calls for fresh, or will it not come out right?

Comment: Do you mean jelly as in spreadable jam in the US sense, or a gelatin in the UK sense?

Comment: Are these pickled? Canned jalapeñ often are, I think sometimes without saying so on the front label (I'd check the ingredients for vinegar, or just taste).

Comment: You could use chopped orange peels as your source of pectin, and make Jalapeno Marmalad. Likely have to rinse off any vinegar first,

Comment: I'd probably make Jalapeños en Escabeche with it ... but I'd drain the jalapeños, and use the liquid as the vinegar when cooking the other ingredients (so they get cooked, but we don't re-cook the jalapeños), then put them into containers to give to friends.  If you don't want it quite as hot, then replace the canning liquid with vinegar.